# Create objects in form with the same value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to build a form that creates 3 records but there is a repeated field in all of these records (the users name).

```
@competition = Competition.find(params[:competition_id])
@entries = Array.new(3) {@competition.entries.build()}
```

The entry has the following fields:
Name - String 
Description - Text

With this current method the user is required to enter their Name in to 3 different boxes for the three different record entries.

What is the rails approach in stopping the user from having to enter in the same data 3 times?

Comment: could you show you form for entries?

Comment: You can add active record validation like validates_uniqueness_of

Answer (score 0):

You need not ask the user for their name three times.

Look into using the nested form_for helper. Something along the lines of

```
= form_for [@user, @competition] do |f|
```

…assuming this is what you want to do. Also, when the form is submitted, you can fill in the duplicate fields before saving the object.

**Disclaimer**: It's been a while since I did Rails. No Rails 4 experience.

Answer (score 0):

Redesign the model so that the repeated attributes are in a has many association with the ones that are always changing. This will give greater flexibility and control in the future.